# Can a task that is killed incorrectly on Linux be considered a memory leak?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, memory-leaks, raspberry-pi

I use a Raspberry Pi [and run Ubunutu Server 20.04 LTS] quite often so it is advantageous to use memory as responsibly as possible. That being said, I run a number of processes that seem to run fairly efficiently with the 4GB of available memory at about ~2GB. Eventually, though, the memory usage seems to grow closer and closer to the 4GB level. While investgating memory usage with `HTOP`, I noticed something with the Python scrips I'm running (I've provided an image of what I'm describing); the processes seem to stack up.
[image: This is a link to the image.]

Could this be because I'm using `CTRL + Z` rather than `CTRL + C` to restart my Python script?

Please let me know if I can be more specific.

Comment: Ctrl-Z will *stop* a process, but it will still exist in a frozen state. Ctrl-C will send SIGINT which, unless you've installed a signal handler, will terminate the process.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JonathonReinhart. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's because you use ctrl-z.  Use ctrl-c to interrupt your processes, by sending them SIGINT.

ctrl-z only puts your process into the background. It will keep running until it needs terminal input, then pause.

Try this when running some terminal program on your rPi. (It works with vi and many other programs.)

- Press ctrl-z
- Then do some shell commands.  `ls` or whatever
- Then type `fg` to resume your suspended process.

Believe it or not, this stuff works exactly the same on my rPi running GNU/Linux as it did on Bell Labs UNIX Seventh Edition on a PDP 11/70 back in 1976. But that computer had quite a bit less RAM.

Comment: Thanks @O. Jones, I will give this a try. Much appreciated.